# how to Show/Hide button C# ASP.Net <No Panel>

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have below code

```
<div class="modal‐footer">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d1">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateBtn" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block invisible" Text="Update" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d2">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitBtn"  OnClick="SubmmitBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block" Text="Submit" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d3">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ApproveBtn" OnClick="ApproveBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block" Text="Approve" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d4">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="RejectBtn" OnClick="RejectBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" Text="Reject" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to show only Update Button, under condition. Example,

```
if a=="Pending"; only UpdateBtn will be shown.
```

Currently I cannot work with Panel (Even it is success, because my function will be corrupted if i use panel)

Please do help me on this. Ive read lot of forum and tried many approaches but failed.

This is how i declare the (aa) in the back code : public string rfcStatus

this is back code:

```
namespace AA.Search
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string _searchText;
    public string aa;
    public string poaQa = "No";
    SearchMgt search = null;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["idno"] != null)
                {
                    _searchText = Request.QueryString["idno"];
                    SearchText.InnerHtml = _searchText;
                    aa = "Pending"
                    BindData();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried with div id or button id? Where do you want to handle this, server side or client side ?

Comment: You can do this with c# code, Hide all buttons except  UpdateBtn    for example, RejectBtn.Visible = false;

Comment: Arshad, yes i tried both, and i cannot hide/show the button. it is server side

Comment: Murad, I can work on it if I am using Panel (Visibility:false/true) but i cannot use Panel, as my function will corrupted

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. Make sure you declare 'a' as a public variable in the code behind and use the code like below. sorry for the formatting..

```
<%
    if (a== 1)
    { %>
  <div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d1">
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateBtn" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block invisible" Text="Update" />
```

```
<%} %><div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d2">
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitBtn"  OnClick="SubmmitBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block" Text="Submit" />
```

**EDIT**

Code behind

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string rfcStatus;

    protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rfcStatus = "1";
        }

    }
}
```

Mark up

```
<div class="modal‐footer">
<div class="row">
<%
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rfcStatus))
    {
        if (rfcStatus== "1")
        { %>
        <div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d1">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateBtn" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block invisible" Text="Update" />
        </div>
        <%
        }
    } %>
```

Comment: yes Ratheesh, the a is public, however, it didnt call the value (accept as null) when i do this approach. This method is invalid for me. I dont know why

Comment: Can you please paste the code behind. make sure the **a** is initialized on page load or before it... If you dont want to initialize, handle the condition at the markup accordingly

Comment: Try to change the value of rfcStatus in the code behind and see it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139451/discussion-between-ratheesh-and-silenthijab).

Answer (score 1):

Try this Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function hideButton() {
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "hidden";
}); 
<script>
```

You can call this function in C# code using the `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Comment: Hi could you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is in simple way is ternary operator

```
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateBtn" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" 
    CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block invisible" Text="Update" 
      visible=" <%= aa == 'Pending' ? "true" : "false"; %> "/>
```

**OR**
Try this ,code behind file

```
  public bool IsUpdateBtnVisible{get;set;}
    if( aa = "Pending") 
     {
       IsUpdateBtnVisible=true;
     }
    else
      {
        IsUpdateBtnVisible=false;
      }
```

ASPX page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateBtn" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" 
  CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block invisible" Text="Update" 
   visible="<%# IsUpdateBtnVisible %>"/>
```

Comment: change  server tag with single quotes, rather than double quotes,remove "" quots to ' ' change   visible='<%= aa == 'Pending' ? "true" : "false"; %> '/>

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding I believe you should do the following.

## js

```
$(function() {
  var aa = ""; // Global Variable

  var btnID = $("#d1"); //Obtain element desired

  if (aa === "pending") { //Used strictly equals for precision.

    $(btnID).show(); //Make sure your buttons are hidden initially if needed with .hide()

  } else {
    $(btnID).hide();
  }
});
```

## aspx

```
<div class="col-md-6" runat="server" id="d1">
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UpdateBtn" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block invisible" Text="Update" />
</div>
```

I hope this helps.